# cannot resolve getBaseContext() in android

Tags: java, android

Hello I am new to android and ran into a strange error. I had this error handling script that I would need to be using through out the project. The code is currently working fine from the signup.java file. The code looks like this

```
 public void error(boolean flag, String etext, String page)
    {
        if(flag==true)
        {
            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

        }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), etext, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        //Redirect to somepage
    }
}
```

I thought since I will be making frequent use of this block I should put it inside a seperate java class and then call it in all other classes I need this functionality so I created a `error.java` file and when I copy pasted this code and imported the `android.widget.Toast` I still get the error that

> Cannot resolve method getBaseContext()

Why this error, when the same code works fine in the other .java class?

Comment: what class are you extending ?

Comment: I had forgotten to extend the `ActionBarActivity` class extending it solved the issue thanks

Comment: If `error.java` is normal java class then no need to extend `ActionBarActivity`. you will need to pass Context in `error.java` to show Toast. simply add one more Context parameter in `error` method`

Comment: Right it is a simple class so your way should be the right way @ρяσѕρєяK

Comment: You should be passing a context parameter to this class from your activity like @ρяσѕρєя K said.