# Android Studio cannot resolve method getBaseContext(), but it used to work

Tags: java, android, android-studio

In my app I'm using Toasts as

```
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Updating...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Which has worked fine until now. Now I all of a sudden get the following error for all of my toasts.

> Cannot resolve method `getBaseContext()`

I found  [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27571590/cannot-resolve-getbasecontext-in-android)  question on here, which was solved by having the class extend `ActionBarActivity`. 
The class my toasts are in is the `MainActivity.java` and extends `AppCompatActivity`, and implements `View.OnTouchListener`. I doubt it has anything to do with this, since the class is extending an `Activity` anyhow.

I have tried cleaning and rebuilding the project several times. Also, I've done an "Invalidate Caches / Restart..."

Comment: You can use getApplicationContext() method or classname.this

Comment: have you tried rebuilding the project?

Comment: post more code, Fragments don't have `getBaseContext()` but rather `getContext()` instead... and we don't really know what's there unless you really tell us.

Comment: @Dipalishah Hmm. I get the same error for both of those.

Comment: @Tony Yup. Multiple times.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating Android Studio did the trick. Sometimes, the solution is so simple.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this. It worked perfectly for me

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Updating...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Try this code too.... Sometimes it would work

```
Toast.makeText(this, "Updating...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Thank you for notifying me..I just missed that

Comment: Instead of using getApplicationContext just try "this"    Toast.makeText(this, "Updating...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

Answer (score 1):

use this

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "your Message", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
Toast.makeText(YourClass.this.getBaseContext(), "Updating...", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

or clean build your project

Comment: clean your whole projecct@Abby or show a screenshot

Answer (score 0):

Best practic for using Toast is create a method in class Utils.class with context

```
public class Utils {
 public static void showToast(Context context, String msg) {
        Toast.makeText(context, msg, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Then u can call this like:

```
 Utils.showToast(context, context.getString(R.string.cannot_connect));
```

i can update my question if u say that u use fragment or activity for calling Toast method.

on the activity just call this, if not help try with getApplicationContext

in fragments create something like:

```
private Context context;
    private Activity activity;

@Override
    public void onAttach(Activity activity) {
        super.onAttach(activity);
        this.activity = activity;
        context = activity.getApplicationContext();
    }
```

But if u not need activity in fragment use:

```
@Override
    public void onAttach(Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        context = getApplicationContext();
    }
```

also try make context

```
private Context context
```

and on OnCreate

```
context = getApplicationContext();
```